# laravel relationship method working incorect

Tags: php, laravel

Method in model User

```
public function news()
{
    return $this->hasMany(News::class);
}
```

Method in model News

```
public function user()     
{    
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
};
```

Work

```
$user=User::all();
dd($user[0]->news->user->name);
```

Not work

```
$news=News::all();
dd($news[0]->user->name);
```

But array objects 'news' i getted

Comment: it should be `$user[0]->name` and not `$user[0]->news->user->name`, but other than that, everything seems should be working. can you please post the result of `dd(news[0]);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is found, the news cannot get its user because he was deleted from the database

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Yurei.

Answer (score 1):

*answer to the original question*:

you have to pass the variable to the included blade file:

```
@foreach($news as $newsCard)
    @include('includes.news.card', ['newsCard' => $newsCard])
@endforeach
{{$news->links()}}
```

---

*answer to the updated question:*

try to eager load the relationship (more efficient):

```
$news=News::with('user')->all();
```

or to load the query every time:

```
$news[0]->user()->name
```

It should work if your foreign key in the `news` table is called `user_id`. Otherwise you have to explicitly specify your foreign key and local key in your model relationships.

Comment: template see object but cant used methods on one page and can on another. `newsCard->id` work on both page, but `newsCard->user->name` isnt

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: yes, i tryed this and get error 'Attempt to read property "user" on null', this error i getting and without ['newsCard' => $newsCard]

Comment: edit your question adding the code of this blade file 'includes.news.card'

Comment: also try `@foreach($news as $newsCard) {{ $newsCard->user->name }} @endforeach` just for testing

Comment: Exactly the same error

Comment: I will try get user name in controller

Comment: newsCard->id work on foreach?

Comment: ok, is not working and in controller, strange

Comment: news belongsTo user rigth?

Comment: yes ```public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    };```

Comment: hmm,   `user->news[0]->user->name ` working

Comment: so the problem is not in the views, but is either in the model or controller. Add those to your question if you'd like us to take a look (tomorrow, I'm off to bed).  Cheers

Comment: another controller did not solve the problem

Comment: if using all() like `News::with('user')->all();` i getted error 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()', tryed use get() instead of all() and again getted null

Comment: if I get news via `News::find(7)` then `$news->user->name` works correctly

Comment: I FOUND PROBLEM, owner marked as deleted. too much stupid problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```html
<div class="container">
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
</div>
 
{{ $users->links() }}
```

Laravel pagination
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination can help you.

Comment: After publish question i saw it and forgot edit, but problem is no in it